# How to succinctly apply an adjective to both nouns when joined with 'and'?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, conjunctions

My question is very similar to [Does an adjective apply to both nouns when joined with 'and'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130207/does-an-adjective-apply-to-both-nouns-when-joined-with-and), where the answer is "it depends, make it clear."

How do I write it clearly, while still being succinct?  The answers in that question add a lot of words compared to the simple (but ambiguous) sentence. Since SE doesn't like links in questions, my specific wording is

> Outside of the federal government and states, typically **only large cities and counties** use the “legislature-executive” model.

Yes, I could write "... only large cities and large counties ..." but I don't want to say "large" twice, and using a synonym seems a bit contrived and maybe even a touch stilted.

Comment: *Only counties and large cities* means that the scope of *large* is only *cities*. To make it apply to both, use *only large cities and large counties*. At the cost of **one word**, your intention is made clear. You don't want to do that, but you said that the only alternatives presented "**add a lot of words**". Only **one** word is needed.

Comment: What Drew said. And to me _large cities and counties_ is fine as it is, and I think _large counties_ is implied there.

Comment: @NVZ: It may be understood, but it may not. It is not implied - any more than is another reading. It all depends on who the readers are and how important it is that they understand correctly. A formal document (e.g. a specification) would not rest on such "implication".

Comment: @Dan consider _fresh fruits and vegetables_. I think most people would assume that the vegetables are fresh as well. But such sentences are subject to misunderstandings nonetheless.

Comment: @NVZ: Maybe most would, but it would still be ambiguous. (Would most assume the same for *fresh fruit and meat*?)

Comment: @Drew (I hope it's fresh meat). I'm with you on this, adding just one word _large_ before _counties_ should be the simplest solution here.

Comment: @NVZ: I know you are. And I agree that many/most people would understand *fresh* as distributed throughout. The unstated part of the question is how important it is for the OP to be unambiguous. It doesn't sound like it's too important, and he mainly wants to avoid repetition.

Comment: @Dan Repeating words isn't always a bad thing. Have you watched _Taken_? "If you don't let my daughter go, **I will** look for **you**, **I will** find **you**, and **I will** kill **you**."

Comment: @Dan I'm not an expert in the language. English is my second, third, or maybe even 5th language. ;) I hope you find a better answer. No brownie points for me.

Comment: To be, or not, that is the question.    :-)    ⁠

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw some comments to the effect that it wouldn't hurt to add just one more word and make it *only large cities and large counties* but that sounds awkward to me.

Parallelism is usually a desirable thing, but it is definitely possible to go overboard.

I started googling around for an actual grammatical term such as "implied parallelism" or "accordioned parallelism" without much success, but I did come across [Mr. Clarity's style blog](http://clear-writing-with-mr-clarity.blogspot.com/2009/08/grammatical-parallelism-parallel_22.html), which points out the great example of Winston Churchill's famous speech of June 4, 1940, where he uses parallelism to great effect, but only where it's really important:

> Even though large parts of Europe and many old and famous States have fallen or may fall into the grip of the Gestapo and all the odious apparatus of Nazi rule, ***we shall not flag or fail***. We shall go on to the end, we shall fight in France, we shall fight on the seas and oceans, we shall fight with growing confidence and growing strength in the air, we shall defend our Island, whatever the cost may be, we shall fight on the beaches, we shall fight on the landing grounds, we shall fight in the fields and in the streets, we shall fight in the hills; we shall never surrender…

There is a lot of parallel construction here, but if Churchill had not preceded all of those repeated "we shall"s with the implied parallelism of "we shall not flag or fail", perhaps Churchill would have emphasized  long-windedness rather than iron determination.

Perhaps. But it does show that parallel construction isn't necessary in absolutely every case. In your case, you can get away without the second "large".