# Adjective describing multiple nouns

Tags: ambiguity

A term used in a contract stated this "**Specialist oils or spark plugs may be required for your vehicle's service.  Specialist oil is at a set cost of £24 whilst if recommended Spark Plugs will be quoted to you on the day of your service.",**

In the first sentence, does "Specialist" describe only "oils" or both "oils" and "spark plugs"?
Does the second sentence clarify anything in the first?

Comment: This is normal, everyday English ambiguity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does an adjective apply to both nouns when joined with 'and' or 'or'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130207/does-an-adjective-apply-to-both-nouns-when-joined-with-and)

Answer (score 0):

When reading only the first sentence, it seems that "specialist" could be for both oils and spark plugs. The second sentence did separate them, so it's clearer that `specialist` is used to describe only oil here. However, it's not 100% clear, and in some very formal situation (like a legal case) one could still argue that `specialist spark plug` is required for the vehicle's service.