# "Given a man walking a dog and a cat,..."

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, punctuation, ambiguity

I want to write a sentence that starts similar to

> Given a man walking a dog and a cat, ...

This could be interpreted as

1. "given a man that is walking both a dog and a cat".
2. "given (a man walking a dog) and (a cat)".

(2) is the intended meaning. I want the reader to mentally parse the sentence as (2) the first time. The actual sentence I have will appear in a technical document, and the reader may become confused if they think I could possibly mean (1).

---

Obviously, if you rewrite the sentence as:

> Given a cat and man walking a dog, ...

this could be interpreted as "Given a cat and a man together walking a dog," which would be incorrect.

---

One fix would be to include "both."

> Given both a man walking a dog and a cat, ...

The function of "both" here is to prepare the reader to expect two things, however, including it is awkward. "Both A and B" is usually meant to emphasize "specifically A and B, not just A or B." The issue is that A=(man walking a dog) and B=(cat) are not, concretely, conditions to be satisfied. Consider

> Given both an integer x and an integer y, x+y is an integer.

versus

> Given an integer x and an integer y, x+y is an integer.

In the first alternative, "both" serves the function of telling the reader "if there is no y (or x), I am not guaranteeing that x+y is an integer." The primary function of "both" in the clause unnecessary and awkward. The second alternative above is preferred.

---

I suspect that I could include some punctuation to make it work. I was thinking em dashes, but this just doesn't look right.

> Given a man — walking a dog — and a cat, ...

**Question**: Is this use of em dashes grammatically correct? If I keep the same words and the order of those words, is there punctuation I can add to reduce confusion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does an adjective or longer modifier apply to both nouns when they are joined with 'and' \[or 'or'\]?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130207/does-an-adjective-or-longer-modifier-apply-to-both-nouns-when-they-are-joined-wi)

Comment: There is no adjective or longer modifier here at all.

Answer (score 0):

Given a man walking a dog, together with a cat.

This reads unnaturally for vernacular sentences, but reads fine for technical writing:

Given a set X, together with two binary operations satisfying the following axioms, we have a vector space.

Comment: 'Reads unnatural' reads unnaturally. [Google 2-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reads+unnatural%2Creads+unnaturally&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creads%20unnaturally%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: your advice rings true

Comment: vernacular sentences as opposed to what?

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

> *Given 1) a man walking a dog and 2) a cat, . . .*

Or:

> *Given a dog-walking man and a cat, . . .*

Answer (score -1):

"Sample:
**Given a man walking a dog and a cat**, ...

This could be interpreted as

"given a man that is walking both a dog and a cat".
"given (a man walking a dog) and (a cat)".**"

**No**, those interpretations are incorrect given the sentence. "walking a dog and a cat" are structurally parallel.

- Given a man walking a dog and a cat, one can only conclude [whatever].
- Given a child screaming bloody murder and crying, one can only conclude [whatever].
- Given a line crossing a circle and a triangle, one can only conclude [whatever]

Comment: OP says: *Given a man walking a dog and **a** cat*. Not: *Given a man walking a dog and cat*. You removed an article. And how would you interpret *Given a man walking a dog and a car*?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Just a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: downvoter: tsk, tsk, tsk

Comment: @TinfoilHat As making no sense at all.